# Calling SQLServer stored procedure from Sybase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase, sap-ase

I'm writing a script in Sybase ASE where I call a stored procedure in SQL Server. The problem I have is that I'm getting an error from Sybase but not from SQL Server.

The Script in **Sybase** is as follows:

```
declare @input varchar(4000)
select @input = '111,222,333,444,555'
exec GATEWAY.MyDataBase..MyStoredProcedure @input
```

And this is the error:

> [Error] Script lines: 1-5 --------------------------
>    Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '555.............................................................................................................................................' to data type int.
>    Msg: 245, Level: 16, State: 1
>    Server: GATEWAY, Line: 0

My stored procedure in **SQLServer**

I don't know why Sybase adds that right padding. The only way I can get it work is declaring the variable `@input` as `varchar(255)` or shorter.

What I tried without luck:

- Adding a rtrim and ltrim in sybase
- Setting the variable as TEXT
- Adding rtrim and ltrim in SQLServer
- adding a `replace(@input,' ', '')`
- Wanted to replicate the problem in SQLServer adding the pad to the right but it still works.

The important thing is that: **I can excecute it from SQLServer but it throws error from Sybase with the same input data**.

Any help would be very appreciated. I guess it has something to do with the size of the varchar but no clue yet.

Comment: What is the datatype of your @input parameter in sql server? And be careful because passing delimited strings is often a poor choice.

Comment: @SeanLange the datatype of the `@input` parameter is varchar(4000) same as this one. You are right but I need to compare values between to tables on each DB and cannot use the gateway too often.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `remote procedure` in Sybase like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "DBA"."uspSQL_CreateTicketsByCaseNo;1"( in @caseNo varchar(8) ) 
at 'SQL;dbName;dbo;uspSQL_CreateTicketsByCaseNo'
```

You can also right-click the `Procedures & Functions` and use the wizard to create a `remote procedure`. Then call the `remote procedure` like this:

```
CALL "DBA"."uspSQL_CreateTicketsByCaseNo;1"( caseNo )
```

It works for me.